# ggplot bar graph: using different colors for overlaid bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

The code is very close to what I'm trying to do. It combines 2 datasets with the required information and produces the plot where the bars are all blue. The only change I would like to make is that the lower part of each bar should be a custom pink color (custom.color::prim_pink) rather than the custom blue color (I photoshopped an example). But I can't figure out how to change just the lower part of the bars.

```
all_dyst_race_overlay <- rbind(all_dyst_race_pvt_lab, all_dyst_gl_race_pvt_lab)

F2_dyst_race <- ggplot(all_dyst_race_overlay, aes(x = fct_rev(name_label),y=value)) +
  geom_col(
    #width = 1
    color = "white",
    fill = custom.color::prim_med_blue() ) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = .1)) + 
  labs(title = "Dystocia Rate and Compliance Rate by Race/Ethnicity",
       x="Race/Ethnicity category",
       y="Cesarean Rate") + 
  coord_flip()+
  theme_custom.) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(
    size = 16,
    color = custom.color::prim_teal(),
    face = "bold",
    hjust = 1,
    vjust = 2.5
  ),axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0))
F2_dyst_race
```

[Plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMMnV.png)
[Plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xglJ4.png)

I tried using scale_fill_manual to manually assign different colors to each column, but I keep getting an error:
Error in `geom_col()`:
! `mapping` must be created by `aes()`
i Did you use `%>%` or `|>` instead of `+`?

```
all_dyst_race_overlay <- rbind(all_dyst_race_pvt_lab, all_dyst_gl_race_pvt_lab)

F2_dyst_race <- ggplot(all_dyst_race_overlay, aes(x = fct_rev(name_label),y=value)) +
  geom_col(
    #width = 1
    color = "white",
    scale_fill_manual(values=c(custom.color::prim_med_blue, custom.color::prim_med_blue,
        custom.color::prim_med_blue,custom.color::prim_med_blue,custom.color::prim_med_blue,
        custom.color::prim_med_blue,custom.color::prim_med_blue,custom.color::prim_pink,
        custom.color::prim_pink,custom.color::prim_pink,custom.color::prim_pink,custom.color::prim_pink,
        custom.color::prim_pink,custom.color::prim_pink))
        
    #fill = custom.color::prim_med_blue() 
    ) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = .1)) + 
  labs(title = "Dystocia Rate and Compliance Rate by Race/Ethnicity for OBI",
       x="Race/Ethnicity category",
       y="Cesarean Rate") + 
  coord_flip()+
  theme_obi() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(
    size = 16,
    color = custom.color::prim_teal(),
    face = "bold",
    hjust = 1,
    vjust = 2.5
  ),axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0))
F2_dyst_race
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!. You put `scale_fill_manual` inside `geom_col`. As a result it gets assigned to the `mapping=` argument which explains the error message your get. Hence, try with `geom_col(...) + scale_fill_manual(...)`. However, to make `scale_fill_manual` work you have to map a variable on the `fill` aes. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared using `dput()`.

Comment: Not only am I new to Stack Overflow, I'm new to R as well. I'm modifying code written by someone else. So I really don't understand what "map a variable on the fill aes" means.

Could we use the HairEyeColor dataset as an example? The hair colors could be the equivalent of the race categories, the number of brown eyes could be the blue part of the bar, and the number of blue eyes could be the pink part of the bar.

Comment: As a first step do `all_dyst_race_overlay <- list(dataset1 = all_dyst_race_pvt_lab, dataset2 = all_dyst_gl_race_pvt_lab) |> dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "dataset")` to create your combined dataset. This will automatically add an identifier column to your data (Of course could you choose more appropriate names). Then you could use `geom_col(aes(fill = dataset), color = "white")` which is meant with to *map a variable on the fill aes*. This should automatically color your bars. Then use `+ scale_fill_manual(values=c(custom.color::prim_med_blue, custom.color::prim_pink))` to use your custom colors.

Comment: And for more help please run `dput(all_dyst_race_pvt_lab)` and `dput(all_dyst_gl_race_pvt_lab)` an copy & paste the output via an edit into your post. Then we have your data and can run your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you include some some data, it will be much easier to give you practical solution.

For what you provide, I think the most common method is to define a group column for your two datasets, so we can group and color them in ggplot(). Example code is like below:

```
all_dyst_race_pvt_lab%>%mutate(condition = '1')
all_dyst_gl_race_pvt_lab%>%mutate(condition = '2')
all_dyst_race_overlay <- rbind(all_dyst_race_pvt_lab, all_dyst_gl_race_pvt_lab)

ggplot(all_dyst_race_overlay, aes(x = fct_rev(name_label),y=value, fill= condition))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(custom.color::prim_med_blue, custom.color::prim_pink))+
  [the rest of your components]
```

You can actually also define the colors for your two groups using HTML color codes in `scale_fill_manual()` like `values=c("#FF00FF", "#0047AB")` (replace these eyeballed ones with the color codes you get from photoshop). There is no need to include a `custom.color` package.